# Is it possible to convert abw to docx or doc offline

Tags: software-recommendation, libreoffice, abiword, word-processor

I am fed up with the poor performance of LibreOffice Writer. So I am using AbiWord Editor now which is lot better than LibreOffice Writer, but there is another problem with Abiword.

AbiWord Editor saves document with .abw file extension, which is not very popular and cannot be opened without abiword application installed on Windows/Linux Machines, although I can save it using pdf but when I want to edit the document on any random machine I am unable to do so.

Is there any possible workaround, or a tool to convert .abw file to .docx file without interfering with my original document signatures.

PS: If possible please suggest a good text editor for editing word and rtf documents.Libreoffice Writer is very poor.

Comment: WPS Office has much better compatibility with the newer Microsoft proprietary format DOCX -> http://wps-community.org/download.html

Comment: @CelticWarrior Thanks I will try that office suite. What do you think about LyX https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LyX. There are very less options for Styles with Abiword.

Comment: I think nothing. It's LaTEX related and I fail to see any relevance regarding your question.

Comment: You have too many requests in one thread, please try to narrow down the question. P.S.: if you wish to use proprietary file formats then you should stick to the software issued by its owner, in this case Microsoft.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa okay I will delete my PS line, if it makes the question to the point. Why should I use propretiary formats on Ubuntu how does libreoffice convert/read docx files.

Comment: I ask myself that same question: if you are working on Linux, why do you want to use this file format? The DOCX format was developed to closely suit  Microsoft Word and pretty much every other software maker has struggled to fully support it. Free (libre) software also means free file formats.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Well I want to convert it to docx format so that I can edit the documents everywhere since abw is not supported everywhere and abiword has no docx format support or converter. Thats why I asked a workaround or standalone converter or some bash magic.

Comment: You can not edit a `.docx` document everywhere.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Technically yes I can because Microsoft office is found nearly everywhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45287/discussion-between-luis-de-sousa-and-chinmaya-b).

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware of the [Abiword's supported formats list](http://www.abisource.com/help/en-US/info/infoformats.html) and save your files according to the best strategy about file formats and conversion. Pay special attention to the part that says *AbiWord cannot export Microsoft Word documents at the moment*.

There are better tools for working with Microsoft's proprietary formats. WPS Writer from [WPS Office](http://wps-community.org/download.html) (formerly Kingsoft Office) handles almost all the aforementioned files

Comment: OP wants stable. It seems WPS is an alpha

Comment: Well, it's working quite stable for me... And their Linux port is and probably always will be in some alpha/beta stage.